# Symfony - Class Omnipay\PayPal\ExpressGateway not found

Tags: php, paypal, omnipay, symfony-2.5

I'm trying to integrate the Omnipay Paypal package with my Symfony2.5 application. I've installed the colinodell/omnipay-bundle package, and followed the instructions on how to set it up.

**Set config as:**

```
omnipay:
    methods:
        PayPal_Express:
            username: ******
            password: *******
            signature: ********
            testMode: false
            solutionType: Sole
            landingPage:  Login
    default_gateway: PayPal_Express
```

**and from the controller :**

```
$paypal = $this->get('omnipay')->getDefaultGateway();
$formData = ['number' => '4242424242424242', 'expiryMonth' => '11','expiryYear' => '2018', 'cvv' => '123'];
$response = $paypal->purchase($formData)->send();
```

**I'm getting the error**

> Class '\Omnipay\Paypal\ExpressGateway' not found"

Is there something I'm forgetting?

Comment: Did you install the `omnipay/paypal` package as well?

Comment: yes, is it different php5.6 from 7 ??
i'm php5.6